# What are the imports to use ContinuousClock() in Swift 5.7/Xcode 14 or if not an import, another means for it to compile successfully

Tags: swift, swift5.7

Am trying to use the new ContinuousClock feature in Swift 5.7 using Xcode 14.0 (14A309) in a command line app with with the statement

`let clock = ContinuousClock()`

I get the following error:

`Cannot find 'ContinuousClock' in scope`

Is there an import missing (I'm importing Foundation)?  The apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/continuousclock?changes=_3) show its in Swift Standard Library which isn't really an import..That doc page also list it as beta, but the [release announcement](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.7-released/) shows it as implemented.

Clues?

Comment: Well as you have already mentioned in your post it comes with Swift 7 • Xcode 14. No need to import anything. It is part of the Swift Standard library.

Comment: It's only available in macOS 13 Beta, if this is a Mac playground or project you will need a beta version of Xcode (14.0 Beta 6 or 14.1 Beta 2 for instance) to have access to it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thats probably the case. OP is probably targeting macOS

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Indeed, command line app on macOS.

Comment: This explains it: https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-5-7-released/60249/14